# Compute all ways to bin a series of integers into N bins, where each bin only contains contiguous numbers

Tags: python, combinatorics

I want find all possible ways to map a series of (contiguous) integers M = {0,1,2,...,m} to another series of integers N = {0,1,2,...,n} where m > n, *subject to the constraint that only contiguous integers in M map to the same integer in N.*

The following piece of python code comes close (`start` corresponds to the first element in M, `stop`-1 corresponds to the last element in M, and `nbins` corresponds to |N|):

```
import itertools
def find_bins(start, stop, nbins):
    if (nbins > 1):
        return list(list(itertools.product([range(start, ii)], find_bins(ii, stop, nbins-1))) for ii in range(start+1, stop-nbins+2))
    else:
        return [range(start, stop)]
```

E.g

```
In [20]: find_bins(start=0, stop=5, nbins=3)
Out[20]: 
[[([0], [([1], [2, 3, 4])]),
([0], [([1, 2], [3, 4])]),
([0], [([1, 2, 3], [4])])],
[([0, 1], [([2], [3, 4])]), 
([0, 1], [([2, 3], [4])])],
[([0, 1, 2], [([3], [4])])]]
```

However, as you can see the output is nested, and for the life of me, I cant find a way to properly amend the code without breaking it.

The desired output would look like this:

```
In [20]: find_bins(start=0, stop=5, nbins=3)
Out[20]: 
[[(0), (1), (2, 3, 4)],
[(0), (1, 2), (3, 4)],
[(0), (1, 2, 3), (4)],
[(0, 1), (2), (3, 4)], 
[(0, 1), (2, 3), (4)],
[(0, 1, 2), (3), (4)]]
```

Comment: You're doing so much on 1 line. Why don't you split it up? It'll be easier to read and modify.

Comment: `list(iterator(list(..)))` is not.

Comment: My mistake, I never read far enough to the right to notice that. All the more reason to split it into multiple lines ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest a different approach:  a partitioning into `n` non-empty bins is uniquely determined by the `n-1` distinct indices marking the boundaries between the bins, where the first marker is after the first element, and the final marker before the last element.  `itertools.combinations()` can be used directly to generate all such index tuples, and then it's just a matter of using them as slice indices.  Like so:

```
def find_nbins(start, stop, nbins):
    from itertools import combinations
    base = range(start, stop)
    nbase = len(base)
    for ixs in combinations(range(1, stop - start), nbins - 1):
        yield [tuple(base[lo: hi])
               for lo, hi in zip((0,) + ixs, ixs + (nbase,))]
```

Then, e.g.,

```
for x in find_nbins(0, 5, 3):
    print(x)
```

displays:

```
[(0,), (1,), (2, 3, 4)]
[(0,), (1, 2), (3, 4)]
[(0,), (1, 2, 3), (4,)]
[(0, 1), (2,), (3, 4)]
[(0, 1), (2, 3), (4,)]
[(0, 1, 2), (3,), (4,)]
```

### EDIT:  Making it into 2 problems

Just noting that there's a more general underlying problem here:  generating the ways to break an arbitrary sequence into `n` non-empty bins.  Then the specific question here is applying that to the sequence `range(start, stop)`.  I believe viewing it that way makes the code easier to understand, so here it is:

```
def gbins(seq, nbins):
    from itertools import combinations
    base = tuple(seq)
    nbase = len(base)
    for ixs in combinations(range(1, nbase), nbins - 1):
        yield [base[lo: hi]
               for lo, hi in zip((0,) + ixs, ixs + (nbase,))]

def find_nbins(start, stop, nbins):
    return gbins(range(start, stop), nbins)
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity - why do you prefer doing the `import` from within the function?

Comment: You can do it however you like.  In general, it's dubious practice for a function to add more to its module's global namespace than necessary.  As-is, the function is "self-contained", and can be dropped into any module without fear of changing anything about the module's behavior (unless the module already happened to define a `find_nbins` global).

Comment: Thanks for this most elegant solution. I have incorporated the snippet in a little module I wrote to find the maximum entropy binning for an integer variable. Available under: 
https://github.com/paulbrodersen/entropy-based-binning

Answer (score 0):

This does what I want; I will gladly accept simpler, more elegant solutions:

```
def _split(start, stop, nbins):
    if (nbins > 1):
        out = []
        for ii in range(start+1, stop-nbins+2):
            iterator = itertools.product([range(start, ii)], _split(ii, stop, nbins-1))
            for item in iterator:
                out.append(item)
        return out
    else:
        return [range(start, stop)]

def _unpack(nested):
    unpacked = []
    if isinstance(nested, (list, tuple)):
        for item in nested:

            if isinstance(item, tuple):
                for subitem in item:
                    unpacked.extend(_unpack(subitem))

            elif isinstance(item, list):
                unpacked.append([_unpack(subitem) for subitem in item])

            elif isinstance(item, int):
                unpacked.append([item])

        return unpacked

    else: # integer
        return nested

def find_nbins(start, stop, nbins):
    nested = _split(start, stop, nbins)
    unpacked = [_unpack(item) for item in nested]
    return unpacked
```